# iphone video zoom feature

Tags: video, zooming, avfoundation

I'm using the AV Foundation Framework in iOS 5 to take some video in my app.  I want to enable video zoom, but I'm having trouble.  I was thinking that I should apply a transform to the images at captureOutput: didOutputSampleBuffer: fromConnection:.  If this is the right idea, how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the UIScrollView's zoom option. Simply sub view the Player on the ScrollView. If that doesn't work then make use of GPUImageView and GPUImageMovie. It worked like a charm for me. Let me know if you need more idea.